# Multiple ggplots printed to a single page in knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, survival-analysis

Slight variations of this question have popped up a lot, but none seem to help me with my plots.

I am using `survminer::ggsurvplot` for survival plots in R and I want to compile the knitr code to a pdf. I have 6 plots so I would like to display them in 2 columns on a single page. My code looks like this (minus 2 plots to save space):

```
<<echo=FALSE, fig=TRUE,out.width = ".45\\textwidth", fig.ncol=2>>=

# Overall Survival for each marker
fit.DFS.AR <- survfit(Surv(TNBC1$DF.time, TNBC1$DFS)  ~ TNBC1$AR.bin,
           data = TNBC1)
fit.DFS.CK <- survfit(Surv(TNBC1$DF.time, TNBC1$DFS)  ~ TNBC1$CK.bin,
           data = TNBC1)
fit.DFS.Cla <- survfit(Surv(TNBC1$DF.time, TNBC1$DFS)  ~ TNBC1$Cla.bin,
           data = TNBC1)
...
# Visualize with survminer
plot.arDF <- print(ggsurvplot(fit.DFS.AR, data = TNBC1 , risk.table = F, xlim = c(0, 60),
       #surv.median.line = "hv",
       xlab="Time (months)", ylab="Overall Survival Probability") +   ggtitle("AR") )
plot.ckDF <- print(ggsurvplot(fit.DFS.CK, data = TNBC1 , risk.table = F, xlim = c(0, 60),
       #surv.median.line = "hv",
       xlab="Time (months)", ylab=" Overall Survival Probability") + ggtitle("CK") )
plot.claDF <- print(ggsurvplot(fit.DFS.Cla, data = TNBC1 , risk.table = F, xlim = c(0, 60),
       #surv.median.line = "hv",
       xlab="Time (months)", ylab=" Overall Survival Probability") + ggtitle("Claudin1") )
...
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot.arDF$plot + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)),
    plot.ckDF$plot + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)),
    plot.claDF$plot + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)),                     
    ncol=2, nrow=3)
```

The result is a single column of figures that run off the page. Is there a way to get the 5 plots together on a single page without switching to rmd? I also tried plotting without the plot labels and without `grid.arrange`.

Answer (score 1):

`survminer` apparently has its own arrange function `arrange_ggsurvplots` which can be used to arrange multiple ggsurvplots on the same page.

```r
# Fit survival curves
require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

# List of ggsurvplots
require("survminer")
splots <- list()
splots[[1]] <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE,
                          ggtheme = theme_minimal())
splots[[2]] <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE,
                          ggtheme = theme_grey())

# Arrange multiple ggsurvplots and print the output
arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = TRUE,
                    ncol = 2, nrow = 1, risk.table.height = 0.4)

## Not run: ------------------------------------
# # Arrange and save into pdf file
# res <- arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = FALSE)
# ggsave("myfile.pdf", res)
## ---------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Details can be found at: http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/survminer/reference/arrange_ggsurvplots.html.